# Run grpc server and client in same node js process

Tags: node.js, grpc

I have a scenario where a process acts as both server and client with gRPC.
The implementation of this can be done in C++ using threads (server waiting in a separate thread).

How can the same be implemented in nodeJS

Answer (score 0):

I think you can spawn/fork the same process and then check if this process is a fork. If so, then process acts as a server, if not - as a client.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the client and server objects in the same process and start using both, and they will both work as expected.